# how to subtract shapes using opencv and c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a square and a circle with the same center point. How do I subtract these two shapes from each other?

any idea would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about it? Say, learning that structuring elements are `CV_8U` matrices. Just try `cv::substract`